# Select2 Widge Reset Selected Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, yii2-widget

How to reset selected value in yii2 widget select2 using jQuery or JavaScript? I've tried to use `$("#select2id").val("").trigger("change");` and it show the placeholder, but the first item is always automatically selected.

**EDIT:** I'm using this widget for make dependency dropdown. the widget that the first item always automatically selected is the dependent widget.

[image: expected result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem. That code is actually working. The order of the code that make the problem. So, be sure to check the code order.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it the select2 way:

```
$("#select2id").select2("val", "", true);
```

With the first two parameters you assign an empty string as a value and the last one is for triggering the change.

Comment: is it different from `$("#select2id").val("").trigger("change");`? in mine it's not produce different result through..

Comment: At least it used to have a different effect. I'm not sure about the current version. Related issue: 
https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1769#issuecomment-61809265